# How to decipher imaging method used in remote sensing images?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, atmospheric-science, spectroscopy, image-processing

I am working on remote sensing for science olympiad (div c) and i am kind of lost on remote sensing image analysis. like how do i look at an image and know it was captured using infrared or microwave or infrared+microwave? does anyone have any tips?

Comment: What kind of picture are you talking of?Usually one talks of picture  in the optical region

Comment: @trula in remote sensing, images can be obtained using many bands of the spectrum

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you have an image of the Earth you also have information about the satellite that has taken the image, as well as the frequency bands you are looking. If you don't have this information, there may be some tricks. When the images are high resolution, they are usually optical images. If the image shows a false-color, medium-resolution composite, it is likely to be a mixture of optical and infrared bands. If the image is RADAR (both microwave and radio waves), often only one band (grayscale) is shown, but in addition there are distortions typical of RADAR images, such as distortions in mountains and tall buildings, known as foreshortening and layover.

Comment: by the way, your question may belong to another stack exchange community